# Where can I find the jars I'm pulling in with Grape?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm having trouble deploying a JAR I created from a groovy script, and I think it's because in the script I'm using Grape's Grab functionality to pull in a few libraries, and then when I build the JAR those libraries aren't included in the class path or anything.

How can I go about converting these @Grab statements to "import" statements?

Comment: why do you think so? what is the error message? where you deploy your jar?

Comment: I'm using the groovy script as a scripted data source in a BIRT report that I'm deploying on Tomcat, but BIRT's logs keep telling me that it can't find the .jar of the datasource that I compiled, despite the .jar being in the WEB-INF/lib directory of the Birt viewer on TC. I'm thinking this may have to do with Grape.

Comment: are u doing something like this? https://github.com/char-com-ua/groodbc/wiki

Comment: Dependencies downloaded by grape should be in `~/.groovy/grapes`

Answer (score 3):

Grape should work if you include all groovy libraries into your application.

OR

use [gradle](https://gradle.org/) to build your library with dependencies, put dependencies (grabs) into `build.gradle` and exclude them from your groovy. in this case you need to put into your application `groovy-all-XXX.jar` with your library and other graped dependencies.

FYI

you can collect all dependencies in a strange way like this:

by default artifacts stored in `~/.groovy/grapes` directory

for windows it's `%USERPROFILE%\.groovy\grapes`

see [here how to customize it](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-RepositoryDirectory)

the simple way to take all jars:

to specify custom empty directory for cache 
and after `Grape` command list all jars in this directory and include them into deploy with your library.

but this like creating custom gradle )